# How to send message to another android mobile using socket programming?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am using API 10 and trying to develop an app for sending text and Multimedia messages to another android mobile using socket programming. What should I do for to fetch the IP address of mobile?

Comment: Nearly impossible if you are talking about Phone2Phone. You'll need a Server with fixed adress or at least domain name to look up adresses and phones to register there. The "mobile" part of "Mobile Phone" is the one to blame ...

Comment: It must be down-voted but i up voted instead..!! And answered in brief too ,,, to get the things ,, How stuff works..!!

Answer (score 0):

Lets explore the concept first..

### Here we go :

> What should I do for to fetch the IP address of mobile?

Which IP address...? Which keeps changing over the fraction of time and which does not hold any static ip...?  You must read and study..

1. Network Systems
2. Operating Systems
3. Data structures
4. Database Systems
5. Software Developmental Life Cycles and Paradigms
6. Information Systems
7. Procedure oriented Languages
8. OOPS languages

Then you must have analytical and reasoning abilities of how things must be developed and how it can be implemented along with above knowledge.

Every `device` on internet may be mobile `phone` or a `computer` holds dynamic ip address.

> I am using API 10 ..??

This does not matters what you use..!!

> Trying to develop an app for sending text and Multimedia messages to another android mobile using socket programming.

socket programming..!! Please Do some basics of `socket programming` implement some sample codes first.

> I have done it all... :(

Then its time to get all books back on the table to clear the concepts again as we do know nothing.. Or very poor a reasoning skills..!!

### How Stuff Works :

Lets take example of any major social media like `whatsapp` and not only whatsapp but it is the very basic concept which every developer can tell you or follow to develop what you said..

1. Program your `app` to communicate with your `web-server` via `sockets`
2. Every App user must register to create account on server.
3. If any user sends message save it into his accounts sentbox on server
4. Check if recipient has a account on this web-server?
5. If yes then copy that message into his accounts inbox
6. Make app to fetch data via sockets if there is a change in his account on web-server
7. These are basics which can be extended to the `IsSent` and `IsReceived` by some tricks
8. Tricks..? Fetch user data via app on which screen user is? and send it to server.
9. The same data can be shared to show `IsSent` and `IsReceived` ..!!

### In Short :

Every app performs socket programming and communicates to the fix server. which has fix static Ip address or a web server. As a end user who does not know programming and basics of software engineering :

> Keeps both phones near to each other and asks another ... I have sent a whatsapp message to your phone.., Look does it received...? Not received yet...???!!!  Get the both phones close to each - other .., so that it will get sent and received soon...  Oooh... See .... I said .. Keep phones closer to receive messages faster..!!  :)